# PHP variable holding an href with an Onclick event

Tags: php

For a jQuery Datatables grid, I'm trying to figure out how I can add a onclick event to the delete link (when I need a double quoted variable string with single and double quotes inside it).

*onlick="return confirm('are you sure?')"*

```
$nestedData[] = "<a href=users_delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "> Delete </a>";
```

Since an onlick event needs both single and double quotes to declare it, how to you get an onclick event added to a HREF that's stored in a variable?

thanks!

Comment: Read about [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [character escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character):

```
$a = "this is \"quoted\"";
$b = 'this is \'quoted\'';
$c = 'this is "quoted"';
$d = "this is 'quoted'";
```